# Is a DropShadowFilter mutable in Flex 3.5?

Tags: apache-flex, dropshadow

I have a dropfilter defined using some bindable variables as parameters.

```
<mx:filters>  
   <mx:DropShadowFilter id="torinofilter" distance="0" color="{dropShadowColor}" 
    blurX="{dropBlur}" blurY="{dropBlur}" strength="8" quality="2" 
    alpha="{dropAlpha}"/>  
</mx:filters>
```

I would like to update the filter in a method call like this:

```
this.dropShadowColor = <new color>  
this.dropBlur = 15.0;  
this.dropAlpha = 0.8;
```

Upon tracing both `this.dropShadowColor` and `torinofilter.color`, I see they have updated to the new color, but the color of the dropfilter doesnt change.

I would prefer not to create a new filter because then I get issues with swapChildren.

Answer (score 0):

Properties of [filters](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#filters) cannot be modified like this.

> To modify an existing filter object, you must use the technique of modifying a copy of the filters  array:
>
> 1. Assign the value of the `filters` array to a temporary array, such as one named `myFilters`.
> 2. Modify the property by using the temporary array, `myFilters`. For example, to set the quality property of the first filter in the array, you could use the following code: `myFilters[0].quality = 1;`
> 3. Assign the value of the temporary array to the `filters` array.

Basically when you read `filters` array of a DisplayObject, flash returns a copy of the array, not the live filters array. Pushing a new filter or updating existing filters will only modify the copy, not the original; you have to assign it back to the array to reflect the changes.

Do this from actionscript instead of mxml.

---

> I would prefer not to create a new filter because then I get issues with `swapChildren`.

`swapChildren` applies only to display objects (UIComponents in case of flex containers).